# Webpack ts-loader `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve`

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I trying to build my app using `webpack` and `ts-loader` plugin.

But get this error:

```
ERROR in ./jobs/createUpdateSimasFilters.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../services/data.service' in '/Users/gefalko/gecars2/jobs'
 @ ./jobs/createUpdateSimasFilters.ts 53:10-45

ERROR in ./jobs/createUpdateSimasFilters.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/appData/simasData/activeFilters' in '/Users/gefalko/gecars2/jobs'
 @ ./jobs/createUpdateSimasFilters.ts 52:22-66
```

file:

```
3 import filters from '~/appData/simasData/activeFilters'
4 const ser = require('../services/data.service')
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "dom"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules"]
}
```

webpack.config.json:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function(env, args) {
  const config = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    target: 'async-node',
    mode: 'development'
  }


  if(args.targetFile === 'createUpdateSimasFilters') {
    config.entry = './jobs/createUpdateSimasFilters.ts'
    config.output.filename = 'createUpdateSimasFilters.js'
  }

  return config
}
```

Comment: When project stopped to compile? After some changes or it does not compile "from the start"? Are paths ok?